# CSS Impressão: Imagem cortada na quebra de página [Resolvido]

Tags: html, css, css3, print

Estou tendo problema ao realizar a impressão, ao utilizar uma imagem, a mesma esta cortando na quebra de página, já tentei utilizar `page-break-inside: avoid;`, não não resolveu.  
O que posso fazer para evitar que as imagens sejam cortadas ao imprimir?
[image: exemplo da imagem cortando na impressão]

```css
p.fullimg {
    page-break-before: avoid;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    margin: 25px 0;
    column-span: all;    
}

p.fullimg img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p class="fullimg">
<img src="20200117170144408ea9.png" >
</p>
```

UPDATE
Inseri a imagem dentro de uma tabela `table>tr>tr>img` com `break-inside: avoid;`.

```css
table.fullimg {    
    width: 100%;    
    border: 0;
    margin: 25px 0;
    column-span: all;
    break-inside: avoid;
}

table.fullimg * {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table.fullimg img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="fullimg">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="20200117170144408ea9.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Tentou colocando `break-inside: avoid;` direto na tag da imagem?

Comment: Sim, mas não resolveu

Comment: Faz um teste colca a imagem dentro de uma table tipo `table>tr>tr>img`e coloca break-inside: avoid; na table e testa. O comportamento da tabela pode ser diferente de uma imagem normal, as vezes pode resolver

Comment: @hugocsl deu certo! é uma gambiara, mas funciona... kkkk a tabela fica cortada, mas a imagem não. Valeu. Print: [link](https://prnt.sc/qqsnzm)

Comment: Cara as células da tabela "cortam" de uma forma diferente nesses casos rss, é do escopo do próprio elemento e display table/table-cell acredito. Quando se sabe o que se está fazendo é um recurso tecnológico, quando não se sabe é gambiarra :D. Testa a consistência dessa solução com imagens de tamanhos diferentes e em outras posições dentro do conteúdo para confirma se o comportamento é estável. Se de certo me fala que posto como resposta ok? 